# Permission denied, logged in with root user

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd, permissions, root, lxterminal

I used root user to change a something in my directory and
I typed in
**sudo -i**
followed by **/etc/hostname**
and it says **-bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied**

Comment: `/etc/hostname` is not a batch file or a command... are you trying to edit it? if so, try `nano /etc/hostname`

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not quite certain why Linux decides to say permission is denied rather than giving a more helpful error the problem here is that you're not telling it what you want to do, you're just giving it the path of a file.

I'm assuming you want to edit the file to change your hostname? In that case you'll want to open it in an editor like nano for example.

```
nano /etc/hostname
```

Remember to add sudo if you aren't already running with *sudo -i*.

Comment: You're correct in so far as it's because `/etc/hostname` is not a command (+1). More specifically, though, commands are just *executable* files, and the problem here is that `/etc/hostname` is not set executable (if it were, you'd get a different sort of error, since it's just a line of text). So the "Permission denied" error is actually correct. There are three basic permissions: Read, Write, and Execute. User root will have the first two on `/etc/hostname` but no one has the last one because there would be no point in doing so. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions

Comment: Ah, good point. I spend to much time in the Windows world. Forgot that whether or not a file is executable is dictated by the permission system in Linux.